# retrieve resultset from MSSQL stored procedure in classic asp

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, ado

I'm not well versed in ASP, but that's what I've got to work with for the moment. I have a stored procedure that generates a resultset which i'd like to handle in classic ASP. I can see the resultset if I run the SP in SQL Management Studio with the same parameter so I know its working.

The stored procedure takes 1 parameter @part, i've testing with the following code and can see the SP is executed using SQL Profiler, but I get a '500 - Internal server error' returned from ASP instead of a resultset displayed.

How do correctly retrieve the resultset?

```
Dim fpart, objCommand, objRecordset
fpart = "SMF10320BRNU12"

Set objCommand = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

With objCommand
  .ActiveConnection = db
  .CommandText = "sp_movements"
  .CommandType = 4
  .CommandTimeout = 240

  .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@part", 200, 1, 20)
  .Parameters("@part") = fpart

  Set objRecordset = .Execute
End With

  for each x in objRecordset.Fields
    Response.Write(x.name)
    Response.Write(" = ")
    Response.Write(x.value & "<br />")
  next
  Response.Write("<br />")
  objRecordset.MoveNext

objRecordset.Close
Set objRecordset = nothing

objCommand.Close
Set objCommand = nothing
```

Comment: It might find this useful - [Answer I've given to working with the `ADODB.Command` object](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21698468/692942).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured this out on my own. After digging though some logs I saw an error which I hadn't spotted previously:

```
Object_doesn't_support_this_property_or_method:_'Close'
```

Turns out I was incorrectly trying to close the command object: `objCommand.Close`

My working solution is:

```
Dim fpart, objCommand, objRecordset
fpart = "SMF10320BRNU12"

Set objCommand = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

With objCommand
  .ActiveConnection = db
  .CommandText = "sp_movements"
  .CommandType = 4
  .CommandTimeout = 240

  .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@part", 200, 1, 20)
  .Parameters("@part") = fpart

  Set objRecordset = .Execute
End With

Do until objRecordset.EOF
  for each x in objRecordset.Fields
    Response.Write(x.name)
    Response.Write(" = ")
    Response.Write(x.value & "<br />")
  next
  Response.Write("<br />")
  objRecordset.MoveNext
loop

objRecordset.Close
Set objRecordset = nothing
Set objCommand = nothing
```

**Note:**

This code also has a Do until loop around added to output all the rows from the recordset, but that wasn't strictly necessary to get something output on the page.

**EDIT**

Edited to reflect comments from Lankymart below, I did need to close the recordset.

Comment: Actually you do need to use `Call objRecordset.Close()` to close the `ADODB.Recordset` your issue was `ADODB.Command` doesn't have a `Close()` method.

Comment: You might also benefit by setting `500-100.asp` script in your error pages so you get detailed output of error messages while developing.

Comment: Thanks Lankymart, i've updated the answer to reflect your comment.