# Using sp_helptext in classic asp

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, asp-classic

When I want to get the definition of a `stored procedure` (in SQL Server) I use SQL Server Management Studio.

I sometimes run the `sp_helptext' to output the definition of a stored procedure.
Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176112.aspx

In a nutshell, I'd like to have a simple html popup window that would output any stored procedure's definition to text.

The asp code below is making a successful connection to my Database, but I'm not getting any output.

```
<% 
' .......
sql = "exec sp_helptext 'some_ProcName_Here'"
objRs.open sql, objConn
Text=objRs("Text")
response.write(Text) 
%>
```

I also attempted creating a new Stored Procedure that takes 1 parameter, which would execute the `sp_helptext`.

```
<% 
' .......
sql = "exec See_Proc_Definition @ProcName=some_ProcName_Here"
objRs.open sql, objConn
Text=objRs("Text")
response.write(Text) 
%>
```

Neither of these display anything, but I don't get any returned errors neither.
Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The issue here is `sp_helptext` produces one row per line so you need to `Do While Not objRs.EOF` and use `objRs.MoveNext` to move the cursor to each row. My guess is the definition you are trying to display contains a blank first line.

Comment: If this is true, then the first line should displayed ? OP says no display ?

Comment: It's a stored procedure, but it's getting called like it's a query

Comment: @WhirlMind The definition must contain a blank line.

Comment: @Mackan True, but that is perfectly viable although personally I would use `ADODB.Command` to execute it.

Comment: @Lankymart Ah, yes - because sp_helptext returns a recordset. And here I had an answer ready using _ADODB.command_ instead ;)

Comment: @Mackan I'm tempted to add a `ADODB.Command` equivalent myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are only displaying the first line of the `sp_HelpText` output. SQL Server returns the output as a single column recordset containing a column called `[Text]`.

This means you need to iterate through the rows to display the rest of the output.

Using your first example;

```vb
<% 
' .......
sql = "exec sp_helptext 'some_ProcName_Here'"
objRs.open sql, objConn
Do While Not objRs.EOF
  Text=objRs("Text")
  response.write(Text)
  objRS.MoveNext
Loop
%>
```

This isn't ideal but will work, from experience *(especially with more complex stored procedures)* I find something like this is better in the long run;

```vb
Dim sql, cmd, rs, data

Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
sql = "sp_HelpText"
With cmd
  'Use your connection string instead of instantiating an ADODB.Connection object.
  .ActiveConnection = conn_string
  .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
  .CommandText = sql
  .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@objname", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 776))
  .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@columnname", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 128))
  Set rs = .Execute(, Array("some_ProcName_Here"))
  If Not rs.EOF Then data = rs.GetRows()
  Call rs.Close()
  Set rs = Nothing
End With
Set cmd = Nothing
```

This method gives you a 2-Dimensional Array containing the row data in the `data` variable. You can then use standard Array techniques to manipulate the output.

```vb
Dim output, row, rows

If IsArray(data) Then
  rows = UBound(data, 2)
  For row = 0 To rows
    output = output & "<br />" & data(0, row)
  Next
  Call Response.Write(output)
End If
```

---

**Links**

- [Using METADATA to Import DLL Constants](https://web.archive.org/web/20210417073339/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/110199-1.shtml) - If your having trouble with the ADO constants (`adCmdStoredProc` etc.) this will fix it for you.

Comment: OP mentions, no display ?

Comment: @WhirlMind As far as the OP can tell no output is displayed, that doesn't mean the code isn't working it just means the first line in the output is blank.

Comment: Bonus point for the _Command_ ;) Also `Execute(, Array("some_ProcName_Here"))` is news to me.

Comment: @Mackan I talk a bit about this approach [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21698468/692942). The `Array()` approach was to me until a few years ago.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I also checked _msdn_ and now I'm left to wonder why I haven't used any of these Execute parameters in my previous +10 years of classic asp coding ;) Some of those would've saved some time for sure (records affected etc.)!

Comment: @Mackan It was a kind of *"Eureka!"* moment when I first discovered it quickly followed by *"I could have used this for so many projects!"* realisation.