# 3709 error while trying to call Stored Procedure in Classic ASP

Tags: stored-procedures, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm trying to call a Stored Procedure from a classic ASP application and I'm getting a 3709 error being thrown. This is a connection could not be... error.

```
On Error Resume Next
set ConnectionStr = "driver=SQL Server;server=***;uid=***;pwd=***;database=***"

Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
With cmd
    Set .ActiveConnection = ConnectionStr
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "storedprocedure"  

    'Input Parameters
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@email", adVarchar, adParamInput, 50, Request.Form("email")) 
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@pass", adVarchar, adParamInput, 50, Request.Form("password")) 

End With 

set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet") 

'rs.Open cmd.Execute
set rs = cmd.Execute 'Here is 3709 Error

If not rs.eof Then 'I get a 3704 Error here because of the 3709 error above
    'Do Things with the RS
End If
Set cmd = Nothing
```

My Stored Procedure is:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[nameofprocedure]
    @email nvarchar(50),
    @pass nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SELECT is, fstname, lstname, [password]
    FROM users
    WHERE email = @email AND [password] = @pass;
    RETURN
END
```

Comment: You need to set `ConnectionStr` to a Connection object not a string.

Comment: Do you mean when I set the active connection?

Comment: It throws the same error regardless of if I manage the connection myself or pass the string to the activeConnection. ADODB.Command should be able to manage the connection for me. I've done:

`set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")`
`Conn.open ConnectionStr`

And passed that to the Active connection just to check, and same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is `ConnectionStr` is a string variable not an object variable so `Set` is not expected. You have two choices, either;

1. Remove `Set` from beginning of `ConnectionStr`.

   ```
   set ConnectionStr = "driver=SQL Server;server=***;uid=***;pwd=***;database=***"
   ```

   to

   ```
   ConnectionStr = "driver=SQL Server;server=***;uid=***;pwd=***;database=***"
   ```
2. Instantiate an object variable in this case it will be an `ADODB.Connection` that you will have to call the `Open()` method on passing the connection string *(unless you are re-using the connection object this is overkill)*. [Brian covers this in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47559108/692942).

---

#### Useful Links

- [Error trying to call stored procedure with prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21698468/692942) *(example of how to structure an `ADODB.Command` call to a database)*
- [ADODB.Parameters error '800a0e7c' Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35530750/692942)

Comment: It turned out to be a combination of a few errors. changing the set and including the Metadata fixed the problem completely.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create and open a connection.  Try this code:

```
Set ConnectionStr = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")  
ConnectionStr.Open "driver=SQL Server;server=***;uid=***;pwd=***;database=***"
```

You might want to rename your variable to something else since it's not really a connection string.

Comment: As Stated in [ADO-API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/command-object-ado)
You only need to persist the connection object if you are using the connection more than once. ADO can handle being passed a connection string instead of an object. I tried using a ADODB.Connection object instead and I have the same results.

Comment: I have never tried that technique.  I guess I learned something new!  However, I would verify your connection string is actually valid.  It sounds like ADO cannot create the connection.

Comment: I'm almost certain I'm using the right connection string. I'm wondering if there could be a security thing blocking my connection? Have you encountered anything like this before. It's not my system I'm working on so if the code itself looks good, I think I need to ask someone about how permissions and whatnot work.

Comment: I suppose that's possible, too.  This isn't something I've encountered though.

Comment: @Wnanjo It is possible but not if you declare the string as an Object Variable, this is wrong `Set StrConnection = "..."` this is right, `StrConnection = "..."`. `Set` is specifically for setting a reference to an object not string variables.

Answer (score 0):

ASP file was missing the Library Reference to ADO Data Objects.

```
<!--METADATA
TYPE="TypeLib"
NAME="Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.6 Library"
UUID="{00000206-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4}"
VERSION="2.6"
-->
```

Comment: This might be true but not the cause of the original error. The issue there was trying to reference a string variable as an Object Reference using the `Set` statement.